# MySQL - insert new id

Tags: mysql

I have to insert 3 records in one time:

```
INSERT INTO table (id, name, parent_id) 
VALUES ('1', 'a', 0), (2, 'b', 1), (3, 'c', 1);
```

What query exists so that I can insert 1st record's ID to `parent_id` of 2nd record and 3rd record?

```
INSERT INTO table (name, parent_id) 
VALUES ('a', 0), (2, 'b', SELECT table.id WHERE table.id=1), (3, 'c', SELECT table.id WHERE table.id=1);
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't do this in a single query.  You can use LAST_INSERT_ID() for the last value inserted by the most recent INSERT statement, but that doesn't help get your parent id values for the subsequent rows.  Do it in two separate statements.

```
INSERT INTO table (name, parent_id) VALUES 
  ('a', NULL);
INSERT INTO table (name, parent_id) VALUES
  ('b', LAST_INSERT_ID()),
  ('c', LAST_INSERT_ID());
```

By the way, use NULL for the root node's parent, not 0.  You don't have a row whose id is 0.

Comment: using twice `LAST_INSERT_ID()` won't cause problems, eh? because on inserting `'c'`, it might get id of `'b'`.

Comment: I just tested this on MySQL 5.5.8.  LAST_INSERT_ID() doesn't change as you insert multiple rows.  It returns the last id generated by the *previous* INSERT statement in the current session.

Comment: @todda.speot.is: there is no any order in mysql tables until you've specified it explicitly in `SELECT`

Comment: No, the rows are not guaranteed to be inserted in any order.  In fact, rows are not guaranteed by SQL to be *stored* in any order regardless of how you insert them.  Relations are sets, and sets have no implicit order.

Comment: @Bill Karwin: to be clear *there is* a way to sort the data physically by `alter table`, but it is not the deal, indeed

Comment: @zerkms: It's implementation-dependent, not part of standard SQL.  In the case of MySQL, the behavior even depends on which storage engine you use.  InnoDB always stores rows by primary key (i.e. a clustered index), whereas MyISAM stores rows in any order, as space permits.

Comment: @Bill Karwin: oops, missed about clustered PK